# TemplateUrl angularJS not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, directive

I have a problem with templateUrl like this
My directory

```
myapp
    js
        home.js
    templates
        profile.html
```

I try this in home.js

```
.state('app.profile', {
    url : '/profile',
    views : {
        'appContent' : {
            templateUrl: '/templates/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController'
        }
    }
})
```

and in my profile.html I have

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <div>
            <p>My content</p>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

It doesn't work, but when I try

```
.state('app.profile', {
    url : '/profile',
    views : {
        'appContent' : {
            template: '<ion-view><ion-content padding="true"><div><p>My content</p></div></ion-content></ion-view>',
            controller: 'ProfileController'
        }
    }
})
```

It work correctly. What's wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: how does the url look like in your browser when you're testing this project? Try `templateUrl: '../templates/profile.html'`

Comment: This is most likely a `<base href="/">` issue within your masterpages <head>. Look into that and you should be able to fix your problem.

Comment: try with templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove the extra `/` before template:

```
.state('app.profile', {
url : '/profile',
views : {
    'appContent' : {
        templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileController'
    }
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import template in top of the script and use it as a "template", not "templateUrl":

```
import profile from '/templates/profile.html';
...

.state('app.profile', {
url : '/profile',
views : {
    'appContent' : {
        template: profile ,
        controller: 'ProfileController'
    }
  }
})
```